# how to use minidom to correctly parse xml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, minidom

I am trying to build a Discord bot in Python that will return information about bus arrivals.  I am using the nextbus api https://www.nextbus.com/xmlFeedDocs/NextBusXMLFeed.pdf which provides an xml feed.
Since bus arrivals will are constantly updated I cannot download the file but instead each time a request comes in from a user I need to look at the latest data.  I looked at [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) but that does not work in my situation (at least I can't get it to work).  Instead I am using [xml.dom.minidom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) instead. That does not work nearly as well as ElementTree.  Since I can't say what will be in the feed until it is accessed it is hard to use `dom.getElementByTagName('tag name')`.  This is because if a particuular bus line is not currently running the prediction xml is changed from having a prediction element to having a 'dirTitleBecauseNoPrediction' tag.  Here is what the xml looks like if no bus is running.

```
<body copyright="redacted">
        <predictions agencyTitle="redacted" routeTitle="redacted" routeTag="redacted" stopTitle="redacted" stopTag="recacted" dirTitleBecauseNoPredictions="To redacted"></predictions>
</body>
```

When the bus is running it looks like this

```
<body copyright="redacted">
   <predictions agencyTitle="redacted" routeTitle="redacted" routeTag="redacted" stopTitle="redacted" stopTag="redacted">
       <direction title="redacted">
              <prediction epochTime="1546570037272" seconds="1228" minutes="20" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="redacted" vehicle="redacted" block="redacted"/>
              <prediction epochTime="1546572437272" seconds="3628" minutes="60" isDeparture="false" affectedByLayover="true" dirTag="redacted" vehicle="redacted" block="redacted"/>
       </direction>
    </predictions>
</body>
```

I would like to be able to parse through the file and see what is present so a decision can be made as to what information to provide to the user.
I am new to doms and xml in general.  Any information on what guides would be helpful would be appreciated. Also, what library or how to use minidom more effectively would be appreciated. I did try Google but with little success.  I am starting to think that Python is not the best language to be doing this project in.  Anyways, thank you in advance.